# MongoDB aggregation framework to group documents that occur within a time range?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Example docs

```
[
  {time: ISODate('2015-07-04T03:12:00.000Z')},
  {time: ISODate('2015-07-04T03:15:00.000Z')},
  {time: ISODate('2015-07-04T04:59:00.000Z')},
  {time: ISODate('2015-07-04T05:01:00.000Z')}
]
```

Expected output

```
[
  {
    '_id': 'groupA',
    'count': 2,
    'min': ISODate('2015-07-04T03:12:00.000Z'),
    'max': ISODate('2015-07-04T03:15:00.000Z')
  },
  {
    '_id': 'groupB',
    'count': 2,
    'min': ISODate('2015-07-04T04:59:00.000Z'),
    'max': ISODate('2015-07-04T05:01:00.000Z')
  }
]
```

Is it possible to use the MongoDB aggregation framework to group documents occurring within some time range of one another? How would you model a $group call to convert example docs to the expected output?

I have tried to convert the time into milliseconds and then create time buckets by using modulo but this results in bins with arbitrary boundaries. For example, 2015-07-04T04:59:00.000Z would be in a separate group from 2015-07-04T05:01:00.000Z even though they should be grouped together.

Comment: What the question is lacking is an explanation of Why? should such times be grouped together. The clear thing is that they are in fact in different hours, and we usually do not "bucket" by the "nearest", but always "round down" to the interval. Unless of course you want to have logic like 5 minutes before the hour and 5 minutes after, then every 10 continuing after that. But if you cannot explain the Why!, then I really do not understand what you are talking about.

Comment: With those examples, which don't even contain everything which is in the expected output, it is hard to help you. Please give at least complete example docs.

Comment: I have a collection with 2000ish documents per day. The documents are individual observations that describe a longer event that typically lasts 20 to 30 minutes. I do not know when the event will occur during the day or how the times will line up with the hour, half hour, or such. I an attempting to use an aggregation to create a rolled-up view that provides an overview of the 4 to 5 events per day instead of 2000 individual observations.

Comment: The groupA and groupB tags a arbitrary strings to denote two separate groups and have no meaning and were not derived from any input data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the time range which you want to group by you may be able to achieve this using MongoDB's [Date Aggregation functions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/).

Using these functions you could project or group the separate elements of the date/time, and combine where needed.

Using your example data the following aggregation pipeline will group your input by hour:

```
{ '$group' : {
    '_id' : {
        'document_day' : { '$dayOfMonth' : '$time' },
        'document_month' : { '$month' : '$time'},
        'document_year' : { '$year' : '$time'},
        'document_hour' : { '$hour' : '$time' }
        },
    'count' : { '$sum' : 1 },
    'min' : { '$min' : '$time'},
    'max' : { '$max' : '$time'}
    }
},
{
    '$project' : {
        '_id' : 0,
        'count' : '$count',
        'min' : '$min',
        'max' : '$max'
    }

}
```

And will give you this result:

```
{ 
  "count" : 1, 
  "min" : ISODate("2015-07-04T05:01:00Z"), 
  "max" : ISODate("2015-07-04T05:01:00Z") 
},
{ 
  "count" : 1, 
  "min" : ISODate("2015-07-04T04:59:00Z"), 
  "max" : ISODate("2015-07-04T04:59:00Z") 
},
{ 
  "count" : 2, 
  "min" : ISODate("2015-07-04T03:12:00Z"), 
  "max" : ISODate("2015-07-04T03:15:00Z") 
}
```

Not sure if this is quite what you're after, but I didn't have necessary rep to leave this as a comment.

Comment: If you read the question carefully the OP does seem to be aware of the date aggregation operators and has even tried something else you can do by effectively rounding the date value with math operators. But their example is quite clear (even if the purpose of Why? in the question is not) in that the expection is for the "4:59" entry to also be in the same grouping as the "5:01" entry. Just as their question states, this will of course put those in seperate groups. So it is important to "fully" read the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. rank your date-points [12:58, 13:01, 13:45, 13:49]
2. take first-differences of the date-points [0min, 3min, 44min, 4min]
3. define a relative threshold (e.g., 1 standard deviation) for splitting the differenced date-points into groups [ [12:58, 13:01], [13:45, 13:49] ]

Comment: and how do you do that in the aggregation framework? I can solve the problem outside of the aggregation framework. I am trying to see if this is possible with a simple aggregation pipeline.